# The image is null, cannot read properties

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
const url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls";

export default function MoviesList() {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        loadData();
        }, []);
        const loadData = async () => {
            await fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setMovie(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }

    function movieCard (movie) {
        return (
            <Card className="movie-card" key={movie.show.id}>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{movie.show.name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>{movie.show.url}
                    <Card.Img src={movie.show.image.medium} />
                    </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        );
    }
    return (
        <>
        <h1>Movie List</h1>
        {movie.map(movieCard)}
        </>
    )
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is I try to access the image URL from the API and use it on my card component. But as soon as I access it, the web goes blank and this is what shows up at console.

[image: Console log error]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: If you log data in your fetch before setting the local state, what does it show?

Comment: hmm i dont understand how to do that..

Comment: instead of setMovie(data) try console.log(data) and see what the output looks like. There is a big possibility that the data has a different structure than what you expect it.

Comment: Ok it shows a lot of things now, it shows 10 data with a lot of hierarchy..

Comment: Yeah, i figured as much :) If you edit your question above with the output you show, I can help you with how to extract what you need.

Comment: @DragonInTraining ok I edited already

Comment: movie.show.image.medium if something like this happen do
move?.show?.image?.medium so, ? operator will do check the undefined 

Also, console.log your data and check if there is any image data or not

Comment: @SourabhSemalty I dont know why this is working haha, it works

Comment: @foreverLearnerDevs bruh... Do learn about ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining this operator it will help you the most in the react 

I'm a newbie also, in react js and having clear concept in js will do help you in react js

Comment: Note that when building webapps, optional chaining is not supported by IE for example. It's a good practice, but know when you should and shouldnt use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to fetching with APIs you need to be ready for larger data structures, since I can only see 1 item in the output above I'll try and show why things are not working.

In your setMovie, you set movie to the entirety of the data.

If we instead go ahead and set movie by using
`setMovie(data[0])`
we instead save that first item.

There might be some future adjustments, but now movie will have access to both `url`, `name` and `medium` in your movieCard function.

Ask yourself if it really is `data[0]` that you need, or if your initial `fetch(url)` needs to be altered to get 1 specific item.

---

Based on your comment below, you want to show movieCards for each item. How I would do that would rewrite abit and make a return that calls movieCard for each movie and then returns that.

`const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);`

I would change to
`const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);` to show that we might be working with several movies depending on what we fetch.

We also go back to your original way of setting the state:
`setMovie(data)` as we now know that you have all items in there.

What we can do next is rewrite your return like this:

```js
 return (
        <>
        <h1>Movie List</h1>
        {movies.map((movie) => (
           movieCard(movie);
        )}
        </>
    )
```

What will happen now is that instead of returning 1 item calling movieCard function, the state containing all the data will iterate and create a movieCard for each movie item it contains.

Comment: So since I need to show that 3 items (Url, Name, and Image) from that 10 items inside the API, not just data[0].

Comment: Your UI should probably be a list of those `<Card>` components, one for each element in `data`.

Comment: If that is your case @foreverLearnerDevs then you should rearrange your code to work differently. This is what I meant by the future adjustment to movieCard function. I will edit my answer to show what I mean in addition to what you just said.

Comment: No worries! Good luck @foreverLearnerDevs!

Answer (score 0):

The render function runs before data arrive, add a condition that if the array is empty, don't make the card

```
function movieCard (movie) {
    if(movie !== ''){
        return (
            <Card className="movie-card" key={movie.show.id}>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{movie.show.name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>{movie.show.url}
                    <Card.Img src={movie.show.image.medium} />
                    </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Also, change data to data[0] as data is in 1st element of the array

```
useEffect( () => {
        loadData();
        }, []);
        const loadData = async () => {
            await fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setMovie(data[0]))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work..